# Convert object {object[]} to string[]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have received `data` of type `object {System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>}`. Parsing this is pretty straightforward:

```
Dictionary<string, object> parsedData = data as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

Now I am trying to access `parsedData["stringArr"]` of type `object {object[]}`. I got stuck when trying to convert this `object {object[]}` to `string[]`.

I can't even iterate this:

```
foreach (object o in parsedData["stringArr"]){}
//returns Exception("...'object' does not contain a public instance definition for GetEnumerator")
```

Comment: That's because `parsedData["stringArr"]` is an `object`, not a `object[]`.

Comment: @SumnerEvans an `object[]` can be an `object`, though. For example: `object x = new object[arraySize];`

Comment: @RufusL It would have to be casted to such in order to be enumerated though.

Comment: `foreach (object o in parsedData["stringArr"]){}` should be `foreach (object o in parsedData){}`

Comment: @RufusL true, but `object` is not iterable, which is the OP's problem. I think the OP needs to change to be a `Dictionary<string, object[]>`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, of course...

Comment: @Kajbo there's no parsing in your code, just casting. The dictionary contains individual objects, not object arrays.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are correct, thanks.

Comment: @SumnerEvans Yeah, I was assuming he doesn't have control over the type he's receiving.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could get the `object` values as `string[]` is to use the `as` cast, just like you did with the original `data`:

```
object data = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"stringArr", new[] {"item1", "item2", "item3"}},
};

var parsedData = data as Dictionary<string, object>;

// cast the object values to string[]
foreach (var o in parsedData["stringArr"] as string[])
{
    Console.WriteLine(o);
}

// Output:
// item1
// item2
// item3
```

Comment: Returning arrays as `object` is ... not neighbourly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Agreed! I'm assuming he doesn't have control over the `data` type, so I just created a sample that conforms to what I think he is receiving.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `parsedData["stringArr"]` is an `object`, not a `object[]`.

I think you want to change the dictionary type parameters:

```
Dictionary<string, object[]> parsedData = data as Dictionary<string, object[]>;
```

Comment: I have tried this a few times but sadly, ``InvalidCastException``

Comment: If `data` is a `Dictionary<string, object>`, then `parsedData` will be `null` here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Dictionary<string, object>`, and you know a particular key's value has a more specific type, cast it as that type:

```
foreach (string s in (string[])parsedData["stringArr"])
```

You will of course receive exceptions if the value at that key is not of that type. A "safer" way of doing it would be to check first:

```
if (parsedData["stringArr"] as string[] data != null) 
{
    foreach (string s in data) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand why but it's ``InvalidCastException``

Comment: As I mentioned, you may receive an exception with the first set of code if the value is not of that type. With the second set of code however, you will not receive an `InvalidCastException`. So you may have transcribed something incorrectly or your code is different from what you've shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you all for your energy to help me to solve it. I would just bash my keyboard for a few more hours without you. I can't understand why extra conversion to `object[]` is required yet, but what works is:

```
Dictionary<string, object> parsedData = data as Dictionary<string, object>;
  if (parsedData.ContainsKey("stringArr"))
            {
                foreach (object o in parsedData["stringArr"] as object[])
                {
                    string myString = o.ToString();
                }

            }
```